# Как в адаптере выделить цветом только определенный айтем

Tags: java, android, adapter, android-spinner

Я использую для `Spinner` собственный адаптер, который должен изменять цвет первого пункта и в открытом состоянии, и в закрытом.
Проблема заключается в том, что после того, как был выбран другой пункт, при развёртывании `Spinner` цвет меняет не только первый пункт, а ещё и который был выбран до этого. Остальные пункты черного цвета, как мне и надо.
Вот код:

```
class CustomAdapter<T> extends ArrayAdapter<T>{
    CustomAdapter(Context cntxt, int resource, T[] objects) {
        super(cntxt, resource, objects);
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup p) {
        if (pos != 0)
            return super.getView(pos, convertView, p);
        TextView tv = (TextView) super.getView(pos, convertView, p);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        return tv;
    }

    @Override
    public View getDropDownView(int pos, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup p) {
        if (pos != 0)
            return super.getDropDownView(pos, convertView, p);
        TextView tv = (TextView) super.getDropDownView(pos, convertView, p);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
        return tv;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Логика работы с адаптером должна явно задавать оба состояния для айтема (как отображать если условие совпадает и если не совпадает), а не одну его часть (если условие совпадает, для остальных другое).

Используйте конструкцию `if` - `else`, явно указывая, как должен выглядеть элемент при совпадении условия и как при не совпадении. Это связано с тем, что вид айтемов переиспользуется и если не указано иного вида, может быть использован созданный ранее вид (для другого айтема).

```
TextView tv = (TextView) super.getView(pos, convertView, p);
if (pos != 0)  tv.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
 else  tv.setTextColor(Color.MAGENTA);
return tv;
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, но изменить надо было код не в методе `getView()`, а в методе `getDropDownView()`. Теперь работает.

Comment: Я ничего не говорил о том, в каком методе надо менять, но вообще, лучше в обоих методах.

Answer (score 0):

Ваша логика отображения должна учитывать `convertView`:

- если `convertView==null` - это первое отображение позиции
- если `convertView!=null`, значит позиция уже сгенерирована и в теории можно использовать предыдущее значение (но очевидно в вашем случае это не так, так как предыдущее значение уже содержит в себе старый цвет).