# При скроле в GridView неправильно отображается информация

Tags: android, gridview

При запуске приложения информация в GridView отображается так, как должна (скрин 1), но при скроле вниз и обратно - начинаются проблемы: сначала с выделением текста (скрин 2), а потом и сам текст теряется (скрин 3).

[image: Скрин 1]
[image: Скрин 2]
[image: Скрин 3]

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_out_rozklad);

        db = new Dbase(this);
        List<Rozklad> rozkls=db.getRozk();
        db.close();
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridV);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ProductAdapter(this, rozkls));
```

Адаптер:

```
public class ProductAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "MyLog ";
    private Context context;
    private List<Rozklad> products;

    public ProductAdapter(Context context, List<Rozklad> products) {
        this.context = context;
        this.products = products;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return products.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return products.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        TextView text;
        String strk;
        if (convertView == null) {
            text = new TextView(context);

        } else {
            text = (TextView) convertView;
        }
        //заново назначаем текст каждый раз при вызове метода
        strk = products.get(position).getRozklad();
        int k = strk.length();
        text.setText(strk);//присвоен текст ячейке
        text.setTextSize(8);//присвоен размер шрифта
        if(strk.length()!=0) {
            char[] chars = strk.toCharArray();
            if ((chars[0] == '0') || (chars[0] == '1') || (chars[0] == '2') || (chars[0] == '3')) {
                text.setBackgroundResource(R.color.gvTop);
            }
        }
        text.setId(position);
        return text;
    }
}
```

Лейаут:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.sky.nestro.e_rozklad.OutRozklad">


        <GridView
            android:id="@+id/gridV"
            android:layout_width="345dp"
            android:layout_height="485dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
            android:numColumns="5"
            android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
            android:verticalSpacing="55dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="7dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
            tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="-29dp"></GridView>>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/608716/177345

Comment: проблема не в этом.

Comment: Вообще-то именно в этом. Главное правило в таких вещах, если есть какие-то изменения вью в `if`, то обязательно должно быть обратное в `else`. Так как вьюшки переиспользуются при скроле, то и возникает такая каша.